# Register Container Itself Using Autofac

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I was wondering is there's any side effect to registering the container within itself

```
IContainer container;
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
container = builder.Build();
builder.RegisterInstance(container).As<IContainer>();
```

and the using it like this

```
builder.RegisterType<IManagmentServiceImp>().As<ManagmentServiceImp>()
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IContainer) && pi.Name == "Container",
            (pi, ctx) => container
));
```

or whether it will even work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your code is not safe because you register an instance before it has been initialized.

If you need to have access to the container inside a component (which is not a good idea) you can have a dependency on `ILifetimeScope` which have `Resolve` methods.

```
public class ManagmentServiceImp 
{
    public ManagmentServiceImp(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
    }
}
```

`ILifetimeScope` is automatically registered within *Autofac* you don't need to add registration for it.

See [Controlling Scope and Lifetime](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/) from *Autofac* documentation for more information.

By the way, it is not a good practice to have dependency on your IoC container. It looks like you use [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) anti-pattern. If you need the container to lazy load dependency, you can use composition with `Func<T>` or `Lazy<T>`

```
public class ManagmentServiceImp 
{
    public ManagmentServiceImp(Lazy<MyService> myService)
    {
        this._myService = myService; 
    }

    private readonly Lazy<MyService> _myService;
}
```

In this case, `MyService` will be created when you first access it.

See [Implicit Relationship](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) from the *Autofac* documentation for more information.

Comment: The _trick_ with `Func` & `Lazy` is outstanding! I didn't know Autofac automatically provides them.

Comment: What about a factory that returns one of many different instances? Injecting all of them (with Lazy<>)?

Answer (score 15):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static void RegisterSelf(this ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    IContainer container = null;
    builder.Register(c => container).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterBuildCallback(c => container = c);
}
```

use it like this: `builder.RegisterSelf();`

Comment: Using this method i get `The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process` after the first request in webapi core and the server is not able to handle requests after that. Changing to ILifetimeScope solved the problem

Comment: As of Autofac 5.0, this no longer works - the signature for `.RegisterBuildCallBack()` has changed and now provides an `ILifetimeScope` instead of an `IContainer`. I'm still searching for a workable fix.

Comment: `IContainer` inherits from `ILifetimeScope` so a cast my work...

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to provide an instance of the container to `builder.RegisterInstance()`, you need to initialize it BEFORE passing it as an argument, which you are currently not doing.  However, if you structure your container builder to build AFTER registration (and container initialization), you can successfully resolve the container instance in your class.

Please note that this is most certainly a design smell in Dependency Injection and you absolutely should not do this.  Your container/kernel should only exist at the top level of your object graph.  If you begin injecting your container, you're almost certainly on your way to a Service Locator Anti-Pattern.

```
void Main()
{
    IContainer container = new ContainerBuilder().Build();
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterInstance(container).As<IContainer>();

    builder.RegisterType<ManagementServiceImp>().As<IManagmentServiceImp>()
       .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IContainer) && pi.Name == "Container",
            (pi, ctx) => container
    ));

    container = builder.Build();
    var instance = container.Resolve<IManagmentServiceImp>();
}

public class ManagementServiceImp : IManagmentServiceImp 
{ 
    private IContainer _container;

    public ManagementServiceImp(IContainer Container)
    {
        _container = Container;
        _container.Dump();
    }
}

public interface IManagmentServiceImp { }
```

Comment: @torvin in what way is the container non-configured and in what way does this not solve the OP's need?

Comment: sorry I accidentally removed my comment. It was "This is wrong, it will register a non-configured container"

Comment: @torvin you still haven't explained how this fails to meet the OP's needs.

Comment: the container will be non-configured in the sense that while you assign the new container `container = builder.Build();` the `builder` will still hold the reference to the previous empty container (created by `new ContainerBuilder().Build()`). You need to use `Register(Func<>)` (see my answer) instead of `RegisterInstance`

Answer (score 1):

Try resolving IComponentContext against the container ;)